# Reading from file without using string

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, stdstring, file-read

I am doing a school project where we must not use `std::string`. How can I do this? In the txt file the data are separated with a ";", and we do not know the length of the words.

Example:

```
apple1;apple2;apple3
mango1;mango2;mango3
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked, always got errors.

I tried using getline, but since it is for string it did not work.
I also tried to reload the `operator<<` but it did not help.

Comment: If you can't use strings, read characters one by one until you encounter a character that you need to handle specially (`;` or `\n`). Basically what `getline` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two entirely separate `getline()`'s. One is `std::getline()`, which takes a `std::string` as a parameter.

But there's also a member function in `std::istream`, which works with an array of `char`s instead of a `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream infile{"apple1;apple2;apple3"};

    char buffer[256];

    while (infile.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ';'))
        std::cout << buffer << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
```

Note: while this fits the school prohibition against using `std::string`, there's almost no other situation where it makes sense.